# Swift protocol extensions for Value(Structures) types

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

```
public struct KZErrorInfo: Unboxable {

var statusCode = -1
var status: String?
var errorMessage: String?

public init() {

}

public init(unboxer: Unboxer) {
    self.statusCode = unboxer.unbox("StatusCode")
    self.status = unboxer.unbox("Status")
    self.errorMessage = unboxer.unbox("Message")
}
```

}

```
protocol KZClientResponse: ETClientResponse {

var errorInfo: KZErrorInfo? { get set }
```

}

```
var errorInfo: KZErrorInfo? {
    get {
        if let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKeyErrorInfo) as? KZErrorInfo {
            return value
        }
        return nil
    }
    set(newValue) {
        if let error = newValue {
           objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKeyErrorInfo, error, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}
```

My objective is to have a default implantation for the protocol KZClientResponse and Xcode is giving me a compile error as below. In the case of value types, how to overcome this issue? Appreciate you suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is indicating, `objc_getAssociatedObject(_:_:)` and `objc_setAssociatedObject(_:_:_:_:)` require `AnyClass` as the first argument. You cannot use Swift structs as `AnyClass`.

Think another way to store `errorInfo` which works with structs.
Why don't you have it as the struct's property?

Answer (score 0):

> ... giving me a compile error as below. In the case of value types, how to overcome this issue?

You can't overcome the compiler error. You're trying to mix apples with oranges. `objc_getAssociatedObject` is, by definition, Objective-C. But Objective-C knows nothing of Swift structs; it cannot possibly see them. The only thing it knows about are what it calls *objects* — that is, classes and their instances. To work with a Swift struct, you cannot use the Objective-C runtime at all: you must operate entirely within Swift itself.